Azure Data Factory: target CSV file losing order of records
I have working pipeline in ADF.
The Source is Snowflake view where records are sorted by row number ascending order, which is a critical condition. The view may include row number column, but ultimate CSV should not contain it. The view output is then exported to blob storage, guess as multiple *_X_Y_X.csv.gz files which then merge into one final CSV with no compression. However, after merging all sorting order is lost.
As far as I understand, there must a way to add sorting via an individual data flow. However, I suspect there should be a way to restore sorting order at the merging stage. Query to the storage container like SELECT a.$1 FROM @STAGE a ORDER BY a.$2  (where a.$2 is row number) returns records in the correct order.
Can any change be done to Copy Data Merge activity to make it keep records order?


Hi @NoNameLittle. My question has nothing to do with Google.

I have found a solution. Not the most effective I guess, but working.
I set "Degree of copy parallelism" in Settings section to 1. This makes the process to ingest files one by one where all the sorting is correct.
